# How can I change php-cli version on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

I am new to using Linux and I broke some php settings while tampering.

If I execute a php script containing: `phpinfo();` it shows the php versions as 5.6,
but via the command line, if I run `php -v` it returns a version of 7.0.

I want to have both versions match.
How can i fix my command line PATH to also use php 5.6?

Comment: check both ini files

Comment: Clearer wording on the problem without changing or adding any details.  
English isn't likely the author's first language.  
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 251, accepted):

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php5.6
```

Please see: [Source](https://tecadmin.net/switch-between-multiple-php-version-on-ubuntu/)

Comment: What to do if I have only one version and need to install more?

Comment: This changed the CLI Version of PHP but the browser one is still the same.

Answer (score 79):

Here is more interactive way:

```
update-alternatives --config php
```

You'll see the list of all available versions and select one of them

Comment: Should be the new answer, much better this way and less error prone and time consuming

Comment: What if I dont have more alternatives? This command shows the notice: There is only one alternative in link group php (providing /usr/bin/php): /usr/bin/php7.2
Nothing to configure.

Comment: @Čamo, update-alternatives allows you to set default php version from the list of installed in your system, so... have you installed something other than php7.2?

Answer (score 45):

From PHP 7.1 => PHP 5.6

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php5.6
```

From PHP 5.6 => PHP 7.1

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.1
```

You can change the versions as you want.

You can check this [tutorial](https://tecadmin.net/switch-between-multiple-php-version-on-ubuntu/#)

Regards!!

Comment: Thank you so much! And I mean SOOOOOOOOO MUCH!

Answer (score 41):

## This explanation is based on Ubuntu 16.04 but is expected to work for other versions too

Most answers here manipulate the php-version by using the command

```
sudo update-alternatives --set ...
```

While the command is quite useful it's never explained what it does exactly. Here comes the explanation, including backup and some options:

### Get the Information

- The command `update-alternatives` is displaying or changing symlinks which reside in an alternative direction which is in Ubuntu usually defined as `/etc/alternatives` but which could be changed too.
- a full list of options related to `update-alternatives` can be shown with the command `update-alternatives --help`, a deeper explanation can be shown with `man update-alternatives`.
- As the command `update-alternatives` is primary changing symlinks in a special folder, the content of that folder can be shown with common commands too, following all items starting with `php` are shown:

> ```
>  $ ls -al /etc/alternatives/php*  
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Jan 19 02:58 /etc/alternatives/php -> /usr/bin/php7.2  
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 31 Jan 19 02:58 /etc/alternatives/php.1.gz -> /usr/share/man/man1/php7.2.1.gz  
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 19 Jan 19 03:00 /etc/alternatives/php-cgi -> /usr/bin/php-cgi7.2  
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 35 Jan 19 03:00 /etc/alternatives/php-cgi.1.gz -> /usr/share/man/man1/php-cgi7.2.1.gz 
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 23 Jan 19 03:00 /etc/alternatives/php-cgi-bin -> /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php7.2
> ```

- to display the items with the command `update-alternatives` use this command:

> ```
> $ update-alternatives --list php  
> /usr/bin/php7.0  
> /usr/bin/php7.2
> ```

- to show more details you can execute this:

> ```
> $ update-alternatives --display php
> php - auto mode
>   link best version is /usr/bin/php7.2
>   link currently points to /usr/bin/php7.2
>   link php is /usr/bin/php
>   slave php.1.gz is /usr/share/man/man1/php.1.gz
> /usr/bin/php7.0 - priority 70
>   slave php.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/php7.0.1.gz
> /usr/bin/php7.2 - priority 72
>   slave php.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/php7.2.1.gz
> ```

Finally we still want to know which php-versions we can link. The following command shows a list of the currently available php-versions in `/usr/bin/`:

> ```
> $ ls -al /usr/bin/php*
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      21 Jan  1 19:47 /usr/bin/php -> /etc/alternatives/php
> -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4385840 Apr  5 18:13 /usr/bin/php7.0
> -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4875488 Apr  5 18:10 /usr/bin/php7.2
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      25 Jan  1 19:47 /usr/bin/php-cgi -> /etc/alternatives/php-cgi
> -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4279672 Apr  5 18:13 /usr/bin/php-cgi7.0
> -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4769272 Apr  5 18:10 /usr/bin/php-cgi7.2
> -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     663 Feb 29  2016 /usr/bin/phpunit
> ```

### Backup the information

- To make an informational backup of these symlinks just save the list in a file and save it on your desktop with this command (adjust the filename `alternatives-php.txt` to your needs):

> ```
> $ echo "command: update-alternatives --list php" > ~/Desktop/alternatives-php.txt
> $ update-alternatives --display php >> ~/Desktop/alternatives-php.txt 
> $ echo "command: update-alternatives --display php" >> ~/Desktop/alternatives-php.txt
> $ update-alternatives --display php >> ~/Desktop/alternatives-php.txt
> ```
>
> if you like you still can add the result of the command `ls` like shown above:
>
> ```
> $ echo "command: ls -al /etc/alternatives/php*" >> ~/Desktop/alternatives-php.txt
> $ ls -al /etc/alternatives/php* >> ~/Desktop/alternatives-php.txt
> ```
>
> ... and the available PHP-versions:
>
> ```
> $ echo "command: ls -al /usr/bin/php*" >> ~/Desktop/alternatives-php.txt
> $ ls -al /usr/bin/php* >> ~/Desktop/alternatives-php.txt
> ```

### Change the PHP-version for commandline

- If we filter first the `man`-documents the list in `/etc/alternatives/php*/` includes 3 lines:

> ```
>  $ ls -al /etc/alternatives/php*  
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Jan 19 02:58 /etc/alternatives/php -> /usr/bin/php7.2  
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 19 Jan 19 03:00 /etc/alternatives/php-cgi -> /usr/bin/php-cgi7.2  
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 23 Jan 19 03:00 /etc/alternatives/php-cgi-bin -> /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php7.2
> ```

- While on the one hand it might be useful to have consistent links for the whole system on the other hand the fact that several php-versions exist already on the system implies that it's used for development and php for `cli`, `web` and `cgi` could be configured differently.
  **Which symlink has to be changed?**
  PHP for web is usually not configured by usage of the symlinks in `/etc/alternatives` and `cli`(commandline) is usually not using the cgi-version or cgi-configuration. So it can be assumed that changing only the symlink for `php` will work for commandline, change of `php-cgi` and `php-cgi-bin` is probably not required.
  Usually the most recent version is linked by default, so the command below is using an older version taken from the list in `/usr/bin/`:

> ```
> $ sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.0
> update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/php7.0 to provide /usr/bin/php (php) in manual mode
> ```

### Control

Checking the change:

> ```
> $: php -v
> PHP 7.0.29-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Apr  5 2018 08:34:50) ( NTS )
> Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
> Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
>     with Zend OPcache v7.0.29-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
> ```
>
> The change was accepted and the used version is an older one now.

- Now we check the version the man-page is written for:

> ```
> $: man php
> ... [SCROLL DOWN]
> VERSION INFORMATION
>    This manpage describes php, version 7.0.29-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1.
> COPYRIGHT
> ...
> ```

This means the PHP-version is consistent with the man-page and the command `man php` returns the right descriptions for the current php-version and **no manual adjustments concerning the man-page have been required**.

Comment: This is very good. I only have PHP 7.0 so gonna install the others.

Comment: A true MVP makes detailed answers like these

Comment: @Sunhat thanks, up-vote of the answer is appreciated :)

Comment: What it I have only one version and need to add other newer version? Dont know how to do it. What should I copy from where to where?

Comment: @Čamo you can list all  versions for you ubuntu version with `sudo apt list php*`.

Comment: @Čamo additional versions can be installed too but that's a bit more complicated and restricted to lower versions if I don't mistake.

Comment: @Čamo at least available versions you can install then with "sudo apt get install php8.0" whereas you have to take the available package you want to install as last part of the command.

Answer (score 4):

check what you have before changing

```
 php -v
```

change everything to php 7.2

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.2
sudo update-alternatives --set phar /usr/bin/phar7.2
sudo update-alternatives --set phar.phar /usr/bin/phar.phar7.2
sudo update-alternatives --set phpize /usr/bin/phpize7.2
sudo update-alternatives --set php-config /usr/bin/php-config7.2
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try setting the path to the correct php version on the terminal command line:

```
set PATH="/usr/bin/php5.6/bin:$PATH"
```

Modify the path to match your own path to PHP 5.6 (ie. if it was installed first, it might be something like "/usr/bin/php").

The "$PATH" at the end appends the current path value, so don't forget to use it.

Answer (score 0):

### Plesk

Just to say, if your server is managed using **Plesk** (like mine is at the time of searching through this question) then you may not have later PHP versions in `/usr/bin`

In this case, your PHP versions will be located in `/opt/plesk/php` so you can instead use the following command as a super user (run `su` first if you're not a super user) to set your PHP CLI version (to 7.3 in this example):

```
echo "alias php='/opt/plesk/php/7.3/bin/php'" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Log out and log back in and.... voila!

#### Notes

1. You must be have super user privileges to run this
2. If you want to set the CLI to a different version then simply replace the `7.3` in the command to whichever version you would like (in the OP's case this would be `5.6`
3. If you want to check which versions Plesk has available for you to use, simply run: `ls /opt/plesk/php`

Source: [Plesk Support](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003766853-How-to-specify-command-line-command-php-version-for-SSH-user-on-the-Plesk-server-)

Comment: $ which php
/usr/bin/php
$ mv /usr/bin/php /usr/bin/php-backup
$ ln -s /opt/plesk/php/7.3/bin/php /usr/bin/php
$ php -v

Comment: When you look into Plesk installer maybe you find more PHP versions that can be installed than the ones that are already on your system.

Answer (score 0):

For PLESK do like that:

```
$ which php
/usr/bin/php
$ mv /usr/bin/php /usr/bin/php-backup
$ ln -s /opt/plesk/php/7.3/bin/php /usr/bin/php
$ php -v
```

and to see what is avaiable to choose from do:

```
/usr/local/psa/admin/bin/php_handlers_control --list
```

[How to Change PHP Cli Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55773523/how-to-change-php-cli-version/76477761#76477761)