# How to replace an existing symlink?

Tags: php, composer-php, debian, php-5.6, php-7.2

I have two commands `php72` and `php` in my terminal,
I need to replace php72(7.2 version) with php(5.6 version)

because the composer that I use say's that I need php 7.2 version, and I don't know how to make the composer use the `php72` command instead of `php`, but the other way is to change the symlink of `php` to `php72`

what I've tried:

```
ln -sf /usr/bin/php72 php
```

so the first path is the bin file of the php executionary file, and the second is the link name? should I set it to php? or what exactly should I put(a path to what?)

cause the command above didn't replaced the php after checking its version it was the same

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change php-cli version on Ubuntu 14.04?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040685/how-can-i-change-php-cli-version-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: Although the versions are different, the principle of the duplicate should work.

Comment: @NigelRen I've tried from the duplicate question, but I get this: update-alternatives: error: alternative /usr/bin/php72 for php not registered; not setting how to fix this?

Comment: Try `update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/php php /usr/bin/php72 100`

Comment: @NigelRen now we're talking, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You may update your alternatives as mentioned in comments as follows :

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.2 100
```

Or if you want to *temporarily* use a specific version of your PHP versions you can use composer under this version/bin as follows :

```
php7.2 /usr/bin/locale/composer
```

note that this path `/usr/bin/locale/composer` may differ on your environment.