# Vagrant uses local installed php version instead of include/defined version

Tags: php, configuration, vagrant

A long time ago I installed WAMP locally using Bitnami and updated each component separately.  I just started using Vagrant to work on a project using Laravel.

The Bitnami version of PHP is 7.0.30.

When I vagrant up it still uses php version 7.0.30.

When I run composer update it also uses php v7.0.30.

I provisioned the box using laravel/homestead version '7.0.0' which includes several versions of php, 7.0, 7.1, 7.2, and 7.3

In the Homestead.yaml file:

```
sites:
    php: "7.2"
```

Yet provisioning does not seem to point it to the updated version of php. It still points to 7.0.30

composer update output:

```
Problem 1
     - This package requires php ^7.1.3 but your PHP version (7.0.30) does not satisfy that requirement.  
Problem 2
     - laravel/framework v5.7.9 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
```

**Q1**: Am I able to keep my local version of PHP as is?  I have several sites that are configured to use that version.

**Q2:** How do I disable the local version 7.0.30 or specify the vagrant box should use another version of php?

It is a Windows 10 Enterprise.

Any help pointing me in the right direction would help.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Can you do that let me know what it says `cd homestead -> vagrant up -> vagrant ssh -> php -v ?` Which version do you get ?

Comment: The version for the `sites` is just for the nginx config. You'll have to change which version of PHP is being used on the command line. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040685/how-can-i-change-php-cli-version-on-ubuntu-14-04/49725126 for info on how to change it.

Comment: There should also be aliases that will allow you to change the php version on the fly. Inside of your VM, try `php72` to see if that changes the command-line version.

Comment: @Whatatimetobealive 

Q: cd homestead -> vagrant up -> vagrant ssh -> php -v ?  

A: PHP 7.3.1

Comment: I removed the path to \Bitnami\wampstack-7.0.30-1\php; from the system path variable.  Now composer does not work.  Restarting and doing vagrant up does not make composer work.  Error message: 'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command, oeprable program or batch file

Comment: You need to run composer within the VM.

Comment: @aynber you are correct.  Newbie mistake.  I did 

    homestead ssh

changed the directory and composer ran!  Thank you aynber:

Anyone else looking for good step by step directions with explanations should check out: https://medium.com/@eaimanshoshi/i-am-going-to-write-down-step-by-step-procedure-to-setup-homestead-for-laravel-5-2-17491a423aa