# How to Change PHP Cli Version

Tags: php, command-line-interface, version

I have Changed PHP Version 7.2 from cPanel however it's successfully changed. but when go to Putty (command line interface) and type

```
Php v-
```

it shows php version is 7.2 but Php-cli version 5.6

```
Php v-
```

> PHP 5.6.40 (cli) (built: Apr  8 2019 15:39:30) Copyright (c) 1997-2016
>
> The PHP Group Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend
>
> Technologies

Comment: Try to restart apache so your changes applied

Comment: Apache has nothing at all to do with using PHP from the command line.

Comment: no worked. but i asked to support they did in a minutes without restarting the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My case it was cPanel I had managed to fix by changing the PHP version.

Answer (score 1):

use the below command

> update-alternatives --config PHP

Answer (score 0):

My Case PLESK and CentoOS:

```
$ which php
/usr/bin/php
$ mv /usr/bin/php /usr/bin/php-backup
$ ln -s /opt/plesk/php/7.3/bin/php /usr/bin/php
$ php -v
```

to see which PHP are avaiable:

```
/usr/local/psa/admin/bin/php_handlers_control --list
```