# Change php-cli version

Tags: php, composer-php, debian

I saw that there were a lot of topics on this subject but I couldn't find anything that would unlock my problem.

I would like to use PHP7.3 all the time. Currently I have a version 7.4 on my server which is useless to me. Apache uses 7.3 without any problems and when I do "php -v", it shows me 7.3 as well.
But when I execute a "composer" command, I get an error telling me that it uses PHP7.4 instead of 7.3.
And also when I run "apt search php-cli" I've this result (7.4):

```
$ apt search php-cli
php-cli/unknown,now 2:7.4+75+0~20200327.22+debian9~1.gbp7ccdd5 all  [installé]
command-line interpreter for the PHP scripting language (default)

php-cli-prompt/oldstable 1.0.2+dfsg-1 all
tiny helper prompting for user input
```

My server is working on Debian 9

If anybody know how can i change my php-cli's version, I'll be glad.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change php-cli version on Ubuntu 14.04?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040685/how-can-i-change-php-cli-version-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: I've already tried that without success unfortunatly.