# Error: Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, shared-hosting, cyber-panel

I am trying to run composer install on my server,(which is a CentOS based machine) and getting this weird error,
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Though output of my phpinfo() in my project folder gives php version as 7.4, but running php -v command shows it as 7.1, Please let me know how to fix it.

Edit: composer -vvv about is showing following-
Running 1.10.15 with PHP 7.1.33 on Linux

Comment: you need to update you `php cli` version what OS you are using

Comment: CentOS version 7(Core)

Comment: `/usr/bin/php7.4 /usr/bin/composer install` -- replace php & composer bin path with yours and see if that works. if it does work, [change cli verion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040685/how-can-i-change-php-cli-version-on-ubuntu-14-04/49725126)

Comment: It is a shared hosting, with multiple websites running on same server, I can change only in a particular folder

Comment: If anything else is not working, please share more details, like the full and exact error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out,
The problem was with php-cli as mentioned. Instead of updating to a newer version or removing old version I created an alias for the binary file of new version of PHP and provided full path to the composer, so my command now looks like this:
[alias(path to new version of PHP)] [alias(path to composer)] [composer command]..