# How to specify PHP version in Apache config per project?

Tags: php, apache

I've recently added a new project named `panel` in the Apache config file. Here is the `VirtualHost`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName panel.lamtakam.com
        ServerAlias panel.lamtakam.com

        ServerAdmin myemail@gmail.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/panel/public

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Notes:

1. I use Apache webserver
2. I don't have `fpm` (for PHP)
3. I have two PHP version installed on the server `7.2` and `7.4` and both are `enabled`.

When I run the project above throw the browser, I get the following error:

> Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 7.4.0".

Which means it's getting executed using `php7.2`. Now I need to force Apache to execute it using `php7.4`. Any idea how can I do that?

Comment: and you need to setup fpm.

Comment: Why do you need to change the php version for that? Specify in your composer.json the PHP version and even better, don't run composer install at all on the webserver, there should not be such a requirement.

Comment: @hakre I've `"require": { "php": "^7.4",` inside the *composer.json* file, but apparently it still uses `php 7.2`. Since still getting error *"Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 7.4.0"."*. Also, what do you mean don't run `composer install`, well, I need to install packages, otherwise, how to install packages?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Ubuntu 1804

Comment: you build your software, e.g. locally or on a build server and then you deploy your package to the webserver. and next to require there is platform, see the link in the close message.

Comment: Remember `composer` is a terminal command. It does not use apache it uses the PHP CLI, and you can decide which PHP CLI you use on the command line

Comment: Check for how to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040685

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks for the link you provided, but the problem I'm currently encountered, is getthig this: https://panel.lamtakam.com/

Comment: On the Lamtakam server, there are PHP `7.2` and `7.4` installed. What to do to make it executing using `7.4`?

Comment: Yea, I think that is saying you are not running PHP7.4 but your requirements in composer say you need to be running PHP7,4